# Utilizar dados do banco de dados em uma opção select (HTML/PHP)

Tags: php, html

Com quais ferramentas eu posso integrar o meu banco de dados com um html/php, a intenção é criar um campo do tipo

`<select>$opção1</select>
<select>$opção2</select>
<select>$opção3</select>
<select>$...</select>`

O que eu tenho em mente é puxar* do banco de dados o nome para colocar no select, seria uma aplicação de registrar uma referencia de determinado produto, a aba select iria informar os fornecedores registrados(através de outra aba) no Banco de Dados.

*puxar com um comando de sql `select nome_fantasia from fornecedores;`

Comment: este valores serão enviados para um banco de dados depois ? se sim, a resposta escolhida como a melhor não irá te atender, mas posso te explicar isso também e responder caso queira

Comment: Sim, a ideia é que o campo "select" trabalhe de forma a preencher o fornecedor do produto, dessa maneira o produto vai pro Banco de Dados sempre com o nome exato do fornecedor.

Comment: irei te explicar através de uma resposta e você verifica se dará certo, mas antes me responda qual o nome dos campos que guardam os nomes dos fornecedores e os códigos ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para exibir registros do banco de dados dentro do seu `select`, deverá utilizar um bloco `PHP` para isso. Desta forma, como irei mostrar abaixo, onde o `value = 'nome_fantasia'` será armazenada dentro da variável `nome_fantasia` que é o name do seu `select` e este value irá enviar o nome do fornecedor

```
<select class="form-control" name="nome_fantasia">
  <option></option>
    <?php 

       $result = "SELECT nome_fantasia FROM fornecedores";
       $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
         echo '<option value="'.$row['nome_fantasia'].'"> '.$row['nome_fantasia'].' </option>';
       }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Simples, faça isso e seja feliz:

```
     <?php $sql  = mysqli_query($conexao, "select nome_fantasia from fornecedores");?>
            <select><?php
              while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ ?>     
                  <option value="<?=  $resultado['id'] ?>"><?php echo $resultado['campo_do_seu_banco']; ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
            </select>
```

Comment: Editei pra ficar mais fácil !

Comment: Que show! eu tava quebrando a cabeça pra montar isso! Muito obrigado cara!

Comment: essa resposta marcada como a melhor não ira inserir dado algum no seu banco de dados, irá apenas listar o select trazendo os dados do banco de dados

Answer (score 0):

Faça um select na tabela e use um foreach para exibir os nome no select

```
<select>
<?php
foreach($select as $valor){
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $valor['nome']?>"><?php echo $valor['nome'] ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```